# Translating some rare irregular verbs?

Tags: sens, verbes, verbes-défectifs

I recently compiled for myself a list of all conjugations of every irregular verb in the French language, for over 350 verbs (as close to all of them as I could get.) I also had to translate the meaning of each verb, of course.

There were, however, about 20 verbs which I could not find English translations for anywhere on the internet, or which were very unusual and I did not understand. Could someone please provide translations for these verbs?

- Aveindre
- Choir
- Contre-battre
- Débouillir
- Démordre
- Dépourvoir
- Déprendre
- Désapprendre
- Embatre
- Messeoir
- Mévendre
- Paître (to graze, but in what sense? Against something, or on grass?)
- Parfondre
- Reclure
- Recomparaître
- Rentrouvrir
- Revaloir
- Se contrefoutre
- Se ressouvenir
- S'entre-nuire
- Sourdre
- Sous-tendre

Comment: It should be “désapprendre” and “sourdre”. Most of the verbs you quote are *very* defective, some of them were totally unknown to me [and I'm a native speaker] (débouillir, parfondre, embat(t)re, aveindre). “Paître” is the way cows and sheeps eat and is the only “normal” verb of the list. Rentrouvrir and recomparaître seem odd to me: I don't think they really exist; it's just common practice to add the prefix “re—” before a verb to indicate repetition. So “recomparaître” and “rentrouvrir” are just (debatable) ways of saying “to appear again (in court)” and “to open slightly again”...

Comment: Désapprendre is exactly “unlearn”.

Comment: @Aššur-bāni-apli Why not try to formulate an answer?

Comment: Laziness and absence of my dictionaries, mostly.

Comment: Maybe you could use [this](http://wikipedia.qwika.com/en2fr/User:Poccil/List_of_irregular_French_verbs)...? Anyway, thanks for this contribution to the list of verbs I'm using for my french sentences random generator (No, I don't use any corpus for it, obviously).

Comment: Nice link. I'll have to compare it against my list to find any missing entries.

Comment: @Kareen I've been trying to figure out how to make a list for as long as I've been a stack exchange user. Do you really have to click the list element button again for each new element? That's the only way I can ever get it to work, which is too much trouble for long lists.

Comment: @Aerovistae Nah, you just need a hyphen followed by a space to create a bullet. Adding a space before the hyphen will add an indent to your bullet.

Comment: Bon bah tant pis pour la traduction, et encore merci @RomainVALERI pour la réponse… dommage.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- **Choir** (*to fall*, defective verb, rarely used)
- **Démordre** (the mechanical action opposed to *to bite*, i.e. to release after a bite. Nearly only used in the idiom *ne pas vouloir en démordre* which means *not wanting to give up* or *hold one's position stubbornly*)
- **Désapprendre** (used frequently, meaning *unlearn*)
- **Paître** (*to feed on grass*, used for ruminant animals mainly)
- **Reclure** (*to lock up (someone)*, synonym of *enfermer*) (**Edit :** more common in its adjective form, *reclus-e*, or the noun *réclusion*, as a side note to Aššur-bāni-apli's comment)
- **Recomparaître** (like said in the question comments : *to appear again in court*, frequently used in legal/lawyers context)
- **Rentrouvrir** (*Entrouvrir* meaning *to open slightly*, *rentrouvrir* is the repetition of this action)
- **Revaloir** (another defective, with the nearly unique usage in the idiom *Je te revaudrai ça !* = *I'll repay you !*, to show gratitude)
- **Se contrefoutre** (offensive or vulgar register, meaning *not to give a damn/give a shit*)
- **Se ressouvenir** ((as for *Rentrouvrir* above), *Se souvenir* meaning *to remember*, *se ressouvenir* means *to remember again*) (**Edit :** Thanks to Aššur-bāni-apli for this clarification of nuance: to remember again *after having forgotten*, which is slightly different...)
- **S'entre-nuire** (describes the mutual action of causing harm/trouble one to each other)
- **Sourdre** (rare verb, meaning *to get out from something*, but is used only for sound, water, or this kind of things, not people or solid objects)
- **Sous-tendre** (hard to translate (any help is welcome !), meaning approximately *to ground (something)*, *to found (something)*, or *to establish the base for (something)*)
  (**Edit :** thanks to the comments we have also these propositions, *to underlie* and the almost-litteral *to subtend* thanks to Kareen, or *to underpin* from StéphaneGimenez)
- **Dépourvoir** (approximately *to deprive*) (**Edit :** a lot more common in the adjective form *dépourvu-e*, thanks to StéphaneGimenez's comment)

The others are very rare (and very old, almost not used any more at all), but with a bit of searching...

- **Aveindre** (*to pull something out of somewhere*, with an effort)
- **Contre-battre** (I didn't find this form, but « contrebattre » exists, meaning *to retaliate/to fire back (between two artillery devices)*)
- **Débouillir** (*to immerse in boiling water*, to cleanse/whiten or to test tincture persistance on clothes)
- **Déprendre*** (*To release (someone) from something/someone else's grasp or dominance*)
- **Embatre** (Technical term used in wood wheels crafting, meaning *to attach a circular piece of iron on a wheel's rim*)
- **Messeoir** (*not to fit (socially or politically)*, or we could say *not to be acceptable*)
- **Mévendre*** (I didn't know this one, but it is rather easy to guess for a native speaker, it means *to sell for no profit or negative profit*, i.e. to sell too cheaply)
- **Parfondre*** (used for enamel/faience/earthenware crafting, but I'm definitely no smith to explain that. Any help is welcome, dear SE people)

---

* Found in an old dictionary (Larousse, 1920), a few precisions :

> **Déprendre** *(pran-dre)* v.a. (Se conj. comme *prendre*) Isoler, dissoudre ce qui était pris, c'est-à-dire collé ou congelé. **se déprendre** v.pr. Se détacher.
>
> **Mévendre** *(van-dre)* v.a. (du préf. *mé* et de *vendre*. - Se conj. comme *vendre*.) Vendre à perte.
>
> **Parfondre** v.a. (du lat. *perfundere*, mélanger). Incorporer les couleurs à la plaque de verre ou d'émail et les faire fondre également.

Comment: I think *sous-tendre* could be translated as underlie (as in an underlying cause) or subtend?

Comment: Apparemment, ressouvenir a aussi un sens (rare et littéraire !) spécifique : http://cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/ressouvenir ; j'avoue que je l'ignorais. Et pour moi, reclure n'existe guère qu'au participe passé, peut-être faudrait-il le souligner ?

Comment: Plus important : félicitations pour ta réponse. Je n'avais pas ce courage.

Comment: @Aššur-bāni-apli Merci, mais pour te retourner le compliment : il se trouve que c'est ton commentaire qui m'a donné le courage de me lancer !

Comment: Cherche le participe passé de *dépourvoir* sur google, tu verras que la langue française n'est est pas complètement dépourvue, contrairement à la fourmi ;-)

Comment: Sous-tendre c'est plutôt *underpin* (au sens figuré), non?.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Bravo pour *dépourvoir*... ! J'avais oublié le participe passé... *Mévendre*, je lis pas mal de journaux/périodiques, jamais vu... peut-être dans certaines presses spécifiques ? (économie ? finances ?)

Comment: Where the hell did you find the word "ruminant"? Never heard that one before, had to look it up. Also, how is "unlearn" used frequently? That seems very unusual, looking at it from an English language perspective. I also am very confused as to the explanation of *sourdre*. Lastly, I'm *really* glad I know the definition of *embatre* now...that's sure to come in handy when I visit France and need to purchase a custom wagon. Honestly though, GREAT answer. Thanks.

Comment: En tout cas, « aveindre » me plaît énormément (il faut admettre qu'il est plus charmant que « galérer à choper » qui serait ma première tentative de traduction en français contemporain). Je vais essayer de le réutiliser.

Comment: @Aerovistae *ruminant* means the same in french and english, but I guess it's much less used in this form in english. *Sourdre* is rare indeed, only used in literature, never in oral/casual context. *Désapprendre* is not used on a daily basis, that's for sure, but I think the majority of native speakers hear it from time to time (hint : before learning useful/adequate knwoledge, you must *unlearn* the bad habits or bad assumptions you had in the first place.).

Comment: Could _contre-battre_ mean _to counter-attack_ or _to **fight** back_ in general?

Comment: @CJ Dennis It's a term reserved for artillery, it would be strange and out of context between two people in the streets... **if** we were *a hundred years ago*. But today? it would be completely unheard of.